# How to find out what the encrytion key is when trying to decrypt message

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography

So I'm trying to run my failed code here, and I find myself looking for the keys used to encrypt messages, but I get nothing. I'm looking for how this bit of code works. I'm supposed to get an encrypted message that has been decrypted and get the two keys which were used to encrypt the message. Here in my test method I have included the messages needed to be decrypted, but instead some of them get encrypted even more. For example, I have these messages ready for decryption:

```
        String decrypt1 = cb.decrypt("UUU VVV EGHI");

        String decrypt2 = cb.decrypt("Pi cddc qt xc iwt rdcutgtcrt gddb lxiw ndjg wpi dc udg p hjgegxht epgin. NTAA ADJS!");

        String decrypt3 = cb.decryptMod("Pi cddc qt xc iwt rdcutgtcrt gddb lxiw ndjg wpi dc udg p hjgegxht epgin. NTAA ADJS!");

        String decTwoKeys = cb.decryptTwoKeys("Hfs cpwewloj loks cd Hoto kyg Cyy.");

        String brake = cb.halfOfString("Qbkm Zgis", 1);

        String decrypt4 = cb.decryptMod(fr.asString());
```

but decryptTwoKeys doesn't seem to be able to  get the halfOfSring method to work correctly (I get  parsed string mixed with letters from both index of 1 and index of 2), nor does it print out the two keys needed to decrypt the encrypted message. I should be getting a letter starting from index of 0 and counting every other line, and also be getting a letter from index of 1 every other line and then compile the two new strings into one after decrypting the hidden message.  Instead I get 0s for both keys. I understand that it may take a longer string for the program to be able to locate the two keys, but when I do use a longer string  such as when I load a text file I get an error saying `Java lang object: out of bounds`. I do get some results, but the program crashes after a certain amount of times the data has been parsed. I would also like to know what key has been used to encrypt the message

```
String decrypt2 = cb.decrypt("Pi cddc qt xc iwt rdcutgtcrt gddb lxiw ndjg wpi dc udg p hjgegxht epgin. NTAA ADJS!");

            String decrypt3 = cb.decryptMod("Pi cddc qt xc iwt rdcutgtcrt gddb lxiw ndjg wpi dc udg p hjgegxht epgin. NTAA ADJS!");
```

This above bit works well, and decrypts to the right message.

```
String brake = cb.halfOfString("Qbkm Zgis", 1);
```

This bit above works well in this example because it does print out `bmZi`, but doesn't seem to work when called in the decryptTwoKeys method.

So how do I find out what the keys used to encrypt the original message are, and two, how do I find out what the key used for encryption is in the strings

```
  String decrypt2 = cb.decrypt("Pi cddc qt xc iwt rdcutgtcrt gddb lxiw ndjg wpi dc udg p hjgegxht epgin. NTAA ADJS!");

  String decrypt3 = cb.decryptMod("Pi cddc qt xc iwt rdcutgtcrt gddb lxiw ndjg wpi dc udg p hjgegxht epgin. NTAA ADJS!");
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's my code so far:

```
import edu.duke.FileResource;


public class CaesarBreaker {

    /**
     * Fint max index in an array
     * @param freqs
     * @return 
     */
    public int maxIndex(int[] freqs) {
        int max = freqs[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < freqs.length; i++) {
            if (freqs[i] > max) {
                max = freqs[i];
            }
        } 
        //System.out.println(max);
        return freqs[max];
        //return max;
    }
    /**
     * 
     * @param message 
     * @return  
     */
    public int[] countLetters(String message) {
        String abc = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        int[] counts = new int[26];
        for (int k = 0; k<message.length(); k++) {
            char ch = Character.toLowerCase(message.charAt(k));
            int dex = abc.indexOf(ch);
            if (dex != -1) {
                counts[dex] += 1;
            }
        }
        //System.out.println(counts);
        return counts;
    }
    /**
     * Decrypt message yhal has been in big letters and encrypted with one key
     * @param encrypted
     * @return 
     */
    public String decrypt (String encrypted) {
        CaesarCipher cc = new CaesarCipher();
        int[] freqs = countLetters(encrypted);
        int maxDex = maxIndex(freqs);
        int dkey = maxDex - 4;
        if(maxDex < 4) {
            dkey = 26 - ( 4 - maxDex);
        }
        //System.out.println(cc.encrypt(encrypted, 25-dkey));
        return cc.encrypt(encrypted, 25-dkey); // we can use encryptMod method
    }







    /**
     * Decrypt message yhal has been in big and small letters and encrypted with one key
     * @param encrypted
     * @return 
     */
    public String decryptMod (String encrypted) {
        CaesarCipherMy ccM = new CaesarCipherMy();
        int[] freqs = countLettersMod(encrypted);
        int maxDex = maxIndex(freqs);
        int dkey = maxDex - 4;
        if(maxDex < 4) {
            dkey = 26 - ( 4 - maxDex);
        }
        //System.out.println(ccM.encryptMod(encrypted, 33-dkey));
        return ccM.encryptMod(encrypted, 33-dkey); // we can use encryptMod method
    }
    public int[] countLettersMod(String message) {
        String abc = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        int[] counts = new int[52];
        for (int k = 0; k<message.length(); k++) {
            //char ch = Character.toLowerCase(message.charAt(k));
            char ch = message.charAt(k);
            int dex = abc.indexOf(ch);
            if (dex != -1) {
                counts[dex] += 1;
            }
        }
        //System.out.println(counts);
        return counts;
    }






    /**
     * In order to decrypt the encrypted String, it may be easier to split the String 
     * into two Strings, one String of all the letters encrypted with key1 
     * and one String of all the letters encrypted with key2 . Then use the algorithm from the
     * lesson to determine the key for each String, and then use those keys and the two key
     * encryption method to decrypt the original encrypted message. 
     * For example, if the encrypted message was “Qbkm Zgis” , then you would split this String into
     * two Strings: “Qk gs” , representing the characters in the odd number positions and “bmZi”
     * representing the characters in the even number positions. Then you would get the key for each
     * half String and use the two key encryption method to find the message. Note this example is so
     * small it likely won’t find the keys, but it illustrates how to take the Strings apart.
     * 
     * This method attempts to determine the two keys used to encrypt the message, 
     * prints the two keys, and then returns the decrypted String with those two keys. 
     * More specifically, this method should:
     *     ○ Calculate a String of every other character starting with the first character of the
     *       encrypted String by calling halfOfString.
     *     ○ Calculate a String of every other character starting with the second character of
     *      the encrypted String.
     *     ○ Then calculate the key used to encrypt each half String.
     *     ○ You should print the two keys found.
     *     ○ Calculate and return the decrypted String using the encryptTwoKeys method
     *      from your CaesarCipher class, again making sure it is in the same folder as your
     *      CaesarBreaker class.
     * 
     * @param encrypted
     * @return 
     */
    public String decryptTwoKeys (String encrypted) {
        CaesarCipherMy ccM = new CaesarCipherMy();
        String firstHalf = halfOfString(encrypted, 0);
        String secondHalf = halfOfString(encrypted, 1);
        System.out.println("firstHalf" + "\t" + firstHalf + "\t"  + "secondHalf" + "\t" + secondHalf);

        int firstKey = getKey(firstHalf);
        int secondKey = getKey(secondHalf);

        System.out.println("firstKey" + "\t" + firstKey + "\t"  + "secondKey" + "\t" + secondKey);
        System.out.println(ccM.encryptTwoKeys(encrypted, firstKey, secondKey));
        return ccM.encryptTwoKeys(encrypted, firstKey, secondKey);
    }

    /**
     * This method should return a new String that is every other character from message 
     * starting with the start position. For example, the call halfOfString(“Qbkm Zgis”, 0) 
     * returns the String “Qk gs” and the call halfOfString(“Qbkm Zgis”, 1) returns the String
     * “bm Zi” . Be sure to test this method with a small example.
     * 
     * @param message
     * @param start
     * @return 
     */
    public String halfOfString(String message, int start) {
        if (start != 1 || start != 0) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (char c : message.toCharArray()) {
            int idx = message.indexOf(c);
            if(idx%2 == start) {
            sb = sb.append(c);
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * This method should call countLetters to get an array of the letter frequencies in String s
     * and then use maxIndex to calculate the index of the largest letter frequency, which is
     * the location of the encrypted letter ‘e’, which leads to the key, which is returned.
     * 
     * @param s 
     * @return  
     */
    public int getKey(String s) {
        int[] freqs = countLettersMod(s);
        return maxIndex(freqs);
    }


    public void testCaesarBreaker() {
        CaesarBreaker cb = new CaesarBreaker();
        FileResource fr = new FileResource();
        CaesarCipherMy ccM = new CaesarCipherMy();



        //("FIRST LEGION ATTACK EAST FLANK!", 23)
        //String decrypt = cb.decrypt("CFOPQ IBDFLK XQQXZH BXPQ CIXKH!");

        //String ret4 = ccM.encrypt("XXX YYY HJKL", 23);
        String decrypt1 = cb.decrypt("UUU VVV EGHI");

        String decrypt2 = cb.decrypt("Pi cddc qt xc iwt rdcutgtcrt gddb lxiw ndjg wpi dc udg p hjgegxht epgin. NTAA ADJS!");

        String decrypt3 = cb.decryptMod("Pi cddc qt xc iwt rdcutgtcrt gddb lxiw ndjg wpi dc udg p hjgegxht epgin. NTAA ADJS!");

        String decTwoKeys = cb.decryptTwoKeys("Hfs cpwewloj loks cd Hoto kyg Cyy.");

        String brake = cb.halfOfString("Qbkm Zgis", 1);

        String decrypt4 = cb.decryptMod(fr.asString());

        //String decrypt5 = cb.decryptMod(fr.asString());

        //String getKey = cb.getKey();
        //System.out.println(ret4);
        //System.out.println(decrypt5);
        System.out.println(decrypt4);

        System.out.println(decrypt1);
        System.out.println(decrypt2);
        System.out.println(decrypt3);
        System.out.println(brake);
        //System.out.println(decTwoKeys);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of bugs in your `halfOfString` method. This one should work:

```
public static String halfOfString(String message, int start) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = start; i < message.length(); i+=2) {
         result.append(message.charAt(i));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Unfortunately, I find your code really confusing and it is highly probable there are some more bugs in other methods.